# why is my discord.js music bot stopping before the song is over?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

my music bot works fine and everything but the song stops playing 10-15 seconds before it ends. my code works fine but this is my only problem and i dont get any errors.

this is my code:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
       const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this smh');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins lol');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins lol');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('Put a song name lol');
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(await ytdl(url, {
                filter: format => ['251'],
                highWaterMark: 1 << 25
            }), {
                type: 'opus'
            })
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`<:pepefingergun:759099199949373511> Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`<:pepefingergun:759099199949373511> Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you followed codelyon's tutorial on youtube. This is an issue with Youtube as it tries to disconnect the stream before the bot is done reading the file.

Go to `npm-modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js` and add these lines in the `FFMPEG_ARGUEMENTS` array:

`'reconnect', '1', 'reconnect_streamed', '1', 'reconnect_delay_max', '4'`

then just restart your bot, and it should be resolved.

Should that not work for you, you may need to replace `ytdl-core` with `ytdl-core-discord` and use this:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');

async function play(connection, url) {
  connection.play(await ytdl(url), { type: 'opus' });
}
```

If you use `ytdl-core-discord` with the `FFMPEG_ARGUEMENTS` I stated above, there will be high quality audio streaming.